# Mac Mini 2011 using latest SDK and OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm planning to buy a mac mini 2011 today for developing iOS apps. My question is can I use the latest iOS SDK and 10.10 yosemite in a mac mini 2011?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/ Yosemite is compatibled with Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)

Comment: It will work, but it will be slow, so you might want to learn Origami or something, to fill the time when Xcode is indexing or building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and even older versions can deal with os x Yosemite, depending on the hardware. Also, as long as you use the newest Xcode, the SDK shouldn't give you any problem.